# como convertir una imagen base64 a tipo File

Tags: archivo, base64

Tengo programada una aplicación que me permite tomar fotos usando la webcam pero es de tipo `base64` y esta foto qeu tome quiero alojarla en una carpeta de mi servidor. Como puedo convertir esta imagen base64 en un de tipo File para poder pasarla por Ajax a mi controller y poder almacenarla

Answer (score 0):

puedes enviarlo tal como esta en base64

solo utiliza  FormData

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('picture', filebase64);

$.ajax({
    url: url, 
    type: "POST", 
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData})
        .done(function(e){
            alert('done!');
        });
```

Comment: y salvarla en un carpeta de mi servidor sin problemas??